# Go server not serving files properly

Tags: http, web, go, webserver, localhost

I am creating a SPA.
I am trying to respond all requests with index.html
(I handle routing on the frontend).

My directory structure look like this:

Backend

-- main.go

Frontend

..(some other files)..

-- index.html

Whole project is located in "C:\Go\Projects\src\github.com\congrady\Bakalarka"

My main.go file looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "../Frontend/index.html")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

When I run my main.go file (using go run), my localhost always responds with "404 page not found".
When I try to serve static content using fmt, everything works fine.

Please help, I'm stuck on this for a really long time and I can't get it to work.
Thanks

Comment: I tried your code, to be sure, but it works here. Since you are using a relative path, have you made sure, you are running the app from within the `Backend` directory and not your projects root directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that if you hardcode relative paths in your source file, the directory which you are in when starting the app matters.

In the current configuration, make sure to start the app from the `Backend` directory, i.e.

*C:\Go\Projects\src\github.com\congrady\Bakalarka\Backend*,

**NOT** your apps root directory

*C:\Go\Projects\src\github.com\congrady\Bakalarka*

or

change the string in the main file to **Frontend/index.html** and run from

*C:\Go\Projects\src\github.com\congrady\Bakalarka*

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers so far. Im running this script:

"go run C:\Go\Projects\src\github.com\congrady\Bakalarka\Backend\main.go"

and my Gopath is "C:\Go\Projects\"

By the way, I think that my Go code worked once, but suddenly it stopped working.
Isn't there a problem with something else? (dependencies, the way that localhost work, etc.)
I think that Go lang don't even find my html file at all.

Comment: This is about the working directory, i.e. the directory you are located in when running the command. As I said in the comment, your code is ok.